# IIS saying "Under Construction" for MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I have created the route as described in http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/deployment/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-vb; however, my site still doesn't show up.  Instead, it displays, "Under construction The site you are trying to view does not currently have a default page. It may be in the process of being upgraded and configured. Please try this site again later. If you still experience the problem, try contacting the Web site administrator."

How can I fix this so that my MVC site shows up?

Comment: What version of IIS are you running?

Comment: I believe I have version 7.5 since I read "7.5 Built-in component of Windows Server 2008 R2/ Windows7" Ref. http://forums.iis.net/t/1171695.aspx

Comment: On second thought, I am told that I am running IIS 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's alot of things that could be wrong when trying to run MVC on IIS 6, but Phil Haack has 2 great blog posts about this, [a general version](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) and [one if you're running .NET 4.0](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx)

There are a couple thing I'd start with though, did you uncheck the box like the image below?  Like he mentions in his blog, it's easy to miss and will prevent the system from working.

[image]